# problema con recuperacion de datos de modelo en laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

hola tengo un problema al recuperar la informacion de un modelo en laravel mi problema va asi tengo los modelos (Liquidaciones, User, Liquidaciones_pago_anticipo) cada uno de estos relacionados pero cuando quiero visualizar los datos de un anticipo me sale el siguiente error

> ErrorException in 44b2139a3a7321e90d8f78ae33533a91 line 31: Undefined
>   property: Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection::$fecha_pago (View:
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\web-imsur-laravel\resources\views\anticipos\show.blade.php)

luego de revisar haciendo pruevas con cada una de las llamadas que hago en mi vista (show.blade.php) 
encontre que el problema me sale cuando realizo la llamada de datos a mi modelo (Liquidaciones_pago_anticipo)

vista show.blade.php

```
@foreach ($code_liq as $anti)

       <li> Fecha pago anticipo : {{ $anti->pago_a->fecha_pago }}</li>

    </ul>
```

y haciendo pruebas con tinker vi que cuando llamo a mis modelos en un consulta mi modelo de de Liquidaciones_pago_anticipo me sale como coleccion y no puedo acceder a sus datos

visualizacion de tinker

```
>>> $pag=IMSUR\Liquidaciones::with(['pago_a','usuario_l'])->findOrFail('5620');
=> IMSUR\Liquidaciones {#737
     cod_columna: 245740,
     cod_liquidacion: "5620",
     clave_muestra: "E92E",
     fecha_ingreso: "2019-10-04 17:52:26",
     fecha_liquidacion: "2019-10-05 12:46:15",
     cod_proveedor: 8058,
     particula: "No",
     cod_cooperativa: 1087,
     cod_transportista: 48725,
     observaciones: "NINGUNO",
     cod_origen: 20,
     cheque: "0",
     anticipo_: 200.0,
     cheque_: "0",
     trans_1: 350.0,
     TMB: 20.75,
     TARA: 1.11,
     HUM: 6.0,
     TMH: 19.64,
     TMS: 18.462,
     IMSUR_ZN: 10.28,
     ZINC: 11.2,
     IMSUR_DM: 0.58,
     PLATA_DM: 1.0,
     IMSUR_PLOMO: 0.0,
     PLOMO: 0.0,
     CLIENTE_ZN: 0.0,
     PRECIO_ZN: 6.9,
     CLIENTE_DM: 0.0,
     PRECIO_AG: 1.0,
     CLIENTE_PLOMO: 0.0,
     PRECIO_PLOMO: 0.0,
     monto: 9914.11,
     mas_transporte: 200.0,
     importe_total: 10114.1,
     estado: "SI",
     debe: "NO",
     cod_grupo_liquidacion: 110528,
     usuario_ingreso: "FVI├æOLA",
     usuario_liquidacion: "FVI├æOLA",
     costo_dolar: 6.86,
     plataforma: "A-1",
     triturado: "NO",
     pago_transporte: "SI",
     cod_persona: 1331,
     devuelto: "NO",
     pago_a: Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection {#740
       all: [
         IMSUR\Liquidaciones_pago_anticipo {#743
           cod_anticipo_pago: 204145,
           cod_liquidacion: "5620",
           fecha_pago: "2019-10-04 17:57:50",
           monto: 200.0,
           cod_persona: 1331,
           cod_grupo_anticipo_pago: 81443,
           usuario: "FVI├æOLA",
         },
       ],
     },
     usuario_l: IMSUR\User {#744
       id: 18,
       name: "GOMEZ JORGE",
       email: "gomez.j@gmail.com",
       created_at: "2020-01-27 10:31:42",
       updated_at: "2020-01-27 10:31:42",
       path: "41Lighthouse.jpg",
       ci: "8485969",
       direccion: "KJASDKJ",
       telefono: "82374687",
       confirmed: 0,
       confirmation_code: null,
       cod_prov: "8058",
       image: "",
     },
   }
>>> $pag->usuario_l->name
=> "GOMEZ JORGE"
>>> $pag->pago_a->monto
PHP error:  Undefined property: Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection::$monto
on line 1
>>>
```

como podria solucionar este problema y que es lo que hice mal

aqui dejo mis modelos, y como estan relacionados  gracias

modelo User

```
class User extends Model implements AuthenticatableContract, CanResetPasswordContract {
    protected $table = 'users';
    protected $primaryKey ='cod_prov';
    protected $fillable = ['ci',
                                      'name',
                                      'direccion',
                                      'telefono',
                                      'email',
                                      'password',
                                      'path',
                                      'confirmed',
                                      'confirmation_code',
                                      'cod_prov'];

    public function liqui_u(){
        return $this->hasMany('IMSUR\Liquidaciones','cod_proveedor',     'cod_prov');
    }
}
```

modelo Liquidaciones

```
class Liquidaciones extends Model
{
    protected $table='liquidaciones';
    protected $primaryKey = 'cod_liquidacion';
    protected $fillable = ['cod_columna',
                           'cod_liquidacion',
                           'clave_muestra',
                           'fecha_ingreso',
                           'fecha_liquidacion',
                           'cod_proveedor',
                           'particula',
                           'cod_cooperativa',
                           'cod_transportista',
                           'observaciones',
                           'cod_origen',
                           'cheque',
                           'anticipo_',
                           'cheque_',
                           'trans_1',
                           'TMB',
                           'TARA',
                           'HUM',
                           'TMH',
                           'TMS',
                           'IMSUR_ZN',
                           'ZINC',
                           'IMSUR_DM',
                           'PLATA_DM',
                           'IMSUR_PLOMO',
                           'PLOMO',
                           'CLIENTE_ZN',
                           'PRECIO_ZN',
                           'CLIENTE_DM',
                           'PRECIO_AG',
                           'CLIENTE_PLOMO',
                           'PRECIO_PLOMO',
                           'monto',
                           'mas_transporte',
                           'importe_total',
                           'estado',
                           'debe',
                           'cod_grupo_liquidacion',
                           'usuario_ingreso',
                           'usuario_liquidacion',
                           'costo_dolar',
                           'plataforma',
                           'triturado',
                           'pago_transporte',
                           'cod_persona',
                           'devuelto'];

    public function usuario_l(){
      return $this->belongsTo('IMSUR\User','cod_proveedor','cod_prov');
    }

    public function pago_a(){
      return $this->hasMany('IMSUR\liquidaciones_pago_anticipo','cod_liquidacion','cod_liquidacion');
    }
}
```

modelo Liquidaciones_pago_anticipo

```
class Liquidaciones_pago_anticipo extends Model
{
    protected $table='liquidaciones_pago_anticipo';
    protected $primaryKey = 'cod_anticipo_pago';
    protected $fillable=['cod_anticipo_pago',
                         'cod_liquidacion',
                         'fecha_pago',
                         'monto',
                         'cod_persona',
                         'cod_grupo_anticipo_pago',
                         'usuario'];

    public function liqui_a(){
      return $this->belongsTo('IMSUR\Liquidaciones','cod_liquidacion','cod_liquidacion');
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

La relación entre Liquidaciones y Liquidaciones_pago_anticipo está definidia como uno a muchos, por lo cual te entrega una colección de modelos.

En este caso tienes dos opciones:

1. Revisar el diseño

   Si estás dudando sobre el por qué no te muestra solo un modelo, cuando tú mismo definiste que es una relación de uno a muchos, puede que hayas cometido un error al momento de diseñar tu base de datos y tengas que replantear dicha relación.
2. Iterar o llamarlo por su índice

   Si definitivamente revisaste el diseño, y confirmaste que la relación uno a muchos es la adecuada, entonces tendrás que llamar a dicho elemento por su índice, o iterar si deseas ver la información de todos los modelos relacionados.

   Índice: `{{ $anti->pago_a[0]->fecha_pago }}`

   Iterando (depende de cómo lo quieras mostrar:

   ```
   @foreach ($code_liq as $anti)

     @foreach ($anti->pago_a as $pago)

     <li> Fecha pago anticipo : {{ $pago->fecha_pago }}</li>
   ```